# Rolling mean returns and sharpe on several time-series at once in R

Tags: r, time-series, finance

I use this script in order to calculate mean rolling returns and mean rolling sharpe ratio for a single etf at a time:

```
library(quantmod)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(roll)
###
tickers = c('afk'); forex = c('EURUSD')   
tiingo_api_key("XXXXX") #wts = c(0.1,0.2,0.25,0.25,0.2) 
price_data <- tq_get(tickers, from = '2019-10-01', to = '2021-01-29',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- tq_get(forex, from = '2019-10-01', to = '2021-01-29',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- forex_data[ ,c(2, 8)]

price_data <- price_data %>%
  # join datasets using date column.
  # non key columns from rhs that have the same names as columns in 
  # the lhs get assigned the suffix "_forex_data"
  left_join(forex_data, by = c("date"), suffix = c("", "_forex_data")) %>%
  # calculate new value of adjusted by dividing by forex value
  mutate(adjusted = adjusted / adjusted_forex_data) %>%
  # exclude adjusted_forex_data column from result
  select(-adjusted_forex_data)

price_data <- na.omit(price_data) 
price_data <- price_data[ ,c(2,8)]
##
xdf <- data.frame()
xdf <- price_data
colnames(xdf)[2] <- "adjClose"
xdf_02 <- xdf %>%
  mutate(lagx = lag(adjClose)) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (adjClose - lagx)/adjClose)%>%
  mutate(rollmeanx = roll_mean(pct_change, width = 68),rollsdx = roll_sd(pct_change, width=68)) %>%
  mutate(roll_sharpe = rollmeanx / rollsdx)

xdf_02 <- xdf_02[ ,c(1, 4, 5, 7)]

#write.csv(xdf_02,'afk_r.csv')
```

I need to repeat this operation for several etfs.
For this purpose I tried this script:

```
library(quantmod)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(roll)

###
tickers = c('xly', 'xlv', 'xli'); forex = c('EURUSD')   
tiingo_api_key("XXXX") #wts = c(0.1,0.2,0.25,0.25,0.2) 
price_data <- tq_get(tickers, from = '2019-08-19', to = '2019-10-19',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- tq_get(forex, from = '2019-08-19', to = '2019-10-19',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- forex_data[ ,c(2, 8)]

price_data <- price_data %>%
  # join datasets using date column.
  # non key columns from rhs that have the same names as columns in 
  # the lhs get assigned the suffix "_forex_data"
  left_join(forex_data, by = c("date"), suffix = c("", "_forex_data")) %>%
  # calculate new value of adjusted by dividing by forex value
  mutate(adjusted = adjusted / adjusted_forex_data) %>%
  # exclude adjusted_forex_data column from result
  select(-adjusted_forex_data)

price_data <- na.omit(price_data) 
price_data <- price_data[ ,c(1, 2,8)]

colnames(price_data)[3] <- "adjClose"
price_data_02 <- price_data %>%
  mutate(lagx = lag(adjClose)) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (adjClose - lagx)/adjClose)%>%
  mutate(rollmeanx = roll_mean(pct_change, width = 10),rollsdx = roll_sd(pct_change, width=10)) %>%
  mutate(roll_sharpe = rollmeanx / rollsdx^5)
```

but it doesen't work properly. This is the dput of price_data02.

```
structure(list(symbol = c("XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI"), date = structure(c(1566172800, 
1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566864000, 1566950400, 
1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 1567728000, 
1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568592000, 
1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 1569283200, 
1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 
1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 1570665600, 
1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 1571356800, 
1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566864000, 
1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 
1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 
1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 
1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 
1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 
1570665600, 1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 
1571356800, 1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 
1566864000, 1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 
1567641600, 1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 
1568332800, 1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 
1569196800, 1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 
1569888000, 1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 
1570579200, 1570665600, 1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 
1571270400, 1571356800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), adjClose = c(103.88979190684, 103.985536180942, 105.940631520236, 
106.096510680224, 103.014000529557, 103.656054210621, 105.123520157882, 
106.773230698533, 106.651057131133, 106.752183731718, 107.124677149076, 
109.040842730252, 109.247378023503, 109.568338069556, 109.302004838183, 
109.941910107034, 110.128764894984, 109.409045218438, 108.834273053662, 
108.989530382645, 108.827860236458, 108.570749369651, 107.757863416592, 
108.300501919417, 107.120516287642, 108.465962815583, 108.199545227096, 
107.750358633043, 109.129846724491, 108.075096442047, 105.832515699236, 
105.961569473432, 107.027904160657, 106.408985827586, 105.658867955606, 
106.324973528198, 106.787293972671, 107.68727179356, 107.752492580939, 
108.604244285425, 108.882370462176, 108.528286758828, 108.098752156478, 
79.7690744415815, 79.1411361629132, 79.6907748306897, 79.3948067613073, 
77.3621365050958, 77.8143629822358, 78.5120834734553, 79.1591091551872, 
79.6413048138808, 79.5765650643146, 79.1234362097159, 79.8078108166086, 
79.9828303406139, 79.1766667827908, 79.5272422185871, 80.6357079172772, 
80.3610764188852, 79.9539261939731, 80.3891963088317, 80.1405701177907, 
80.0521265098073, 80.455259611697, 81.2234506709137, 80.9154011793777, 
80.1550223863104, 80.0379887611256, 79.7427685476557, 79.3351813102774, 
80.3786481095186, 79.4897334845071, 78.1095846438923, 78.5264905136837, 
79.8090839437686, 79.4299037039426, 78.1920270560489, 78.5873352799982, 
78.7947931577411, 79.2211265351062, 79.2732953079122, 80.6482408791092, 
80.4180877363704, 80.541688641759, 80.0837798356084, 65.5316291319365, 
65.1905505248625, 65.5636513034318, 65.7399118984554, 63.8180764075688, 
64.0429801055418, 64.9374155819368, 66.0930691100842, 66.6878168783335, 
66.1144476016407, 66.529346485538, 67.6427423430565, 67.7458012282476, 
67.8875770062091, 68.6161415417236, 69.5324528883564, 69.3622868620804, 
69.4247838104348, 69.893912323993, 69.5359752503656, 69.3616314471594, 
69.033862777913, 68.8724115050268, 68.8456157054001, 68.4405021069962, 
69.1184940526835, 69.345285107955, 69.0237442710668, 69.4092222987107, 
67.6575658763924, 66.1922748854133, 66.3878761442095, 67.1240973679064, 
66.6914199010372, 65.8941095924985, 66.3089478833794, 66.7582685555905, 
67.8212228997667, 67.7634712310145, 68.2513378525342, 68.1106187139345, 
68.0448169006413, 67.3224024690253), lagx = c(NA, 103.88979190684, 
103.985536180942, 105.940631520236, 106.096510680224, 103.014000529557, 
103.656054210621, 105.123520157882, 106.773230698533, 106.651057131133, 
106.752183731718, 107.124677149076, 109.040842730252, 109.247378023503, 
109.568338069556, 109.302004838183, 109.941910107034, 110.128764894984, 
109.409045218438, 108.834273053662, 108.989530382645, 108.827860236458, 
108.570749369651, 107.757863416592, 108.300501919417, 107.120516287642, 
108.465962815583, 108.199545227096, 107.750358633043, 109.129846724491, 
108.075096442047, 105.832515699236, 105.961569473432, 107.027904160657, 
106.408985827586, 105.658867955606, 106.324973528198, 106.787293972671, 
107.68727179356, 107.752492580939, 108.604244285425, 108.882370462176, 
108.528286758828, 108.098752156478, 79.7690744415815, 79.1411361629132, 
79.6907748306897, 79.3948067613073, 77.3621365050958, 77.8143629822358, 
78.5120834734553, 79.1591091551872, 79.6413048138808, 79.5765650643146, 
79.1234362097159, 79.8078108166086, 79.9828303406139, 79.1766667827908, 
79.5272422185871, 80.6357079172772, 80.3610764188852, 79.9539261939731, 
80.3891963088317, 80.1405701177907, 80.0521265098073, 80.455259611697, 
81.2234506709137, 80.9154011793777, 80.1550223863104, 80.0379887611256, 
79.7427685476557, 79.3351813102774, 80.3786481095186, 79.4897334845071, 
78.1095846438923, 78.5264905136837, 79.8090839437686, 79.4299037039426, 
78.1920270560489, 78.5873352799982, 78.7947931577411, 79.2211265351062, 
79.2732953079122, 80.6482408791092, 80.4180877363704, 80.541688641759, 
80.0837798356084, 65.5316291319365, 65.1905505248625, 65.5636513034318, 
65.7399118984554, 63.8180764075688, 64.0429801055418, 64.9374155819368, 
66.0930691100842, 66.6878168783335, 66.1144476016407, 66.529346485538, 
67.6427423430565, 67.7458012282476, 67.8875770062091, 68.6161415417236, 
69.5324528883564, 69.3622868620804, 69.4247838104348, 69.893912323993, 
69.5359752503656, 69.3616314471594, 69.033862777913, 68.8724115050268, 
68.8456157054001, 68.4405021069962, 69.1184940526835, 69.345285107955, 
69.0237442710668, 69.4092222987107, 67.6575658763924, 66.1922748854133, 
66.3878761442095, 67.1240973679064, 66.6914199010372, 65.8941095924985, 
66.3089478833794, 66.7582685555905, 67.8212228997667, 67.7634712310145, 
68.2513378525342, 68.1106187139345, 68.0448169006413), pct_change = c(NA, 
0.000920746073145609, 0.0184546317238109, 0.00146922042005707, 
-0.0299232156291454, 0.00619407796248412, 0.0139594445187539, 
0.01545060058461, -0.00114554483271719, 0.000947302406849019, 
0.0034771952389569, 0.017572916103711, 0.0018905286056997, 0.00292931381188991, 
-0.00243667288415593, 0.00582039431758291, 0.00169669375777951, 
-0.00657824657101311, -0.00528116877752874, 0.00142451599193398, 
-0.00148555843913384, -0.00236814121943363, -0.00754363465723802, 
0.00501048927020529, -0.0110154961221968, 0.0124043201481387, 
-0.00246228011335603, -0.00416877122036123, 0.0126407956471404, 
-0.00975942022878049, -0.0211899030084918, 0.0012179299989351, 
0.00996314648583695, -0.00581641041174378, -0.00709943127816679, 
0.00626480826177106, 0.00432935817804974, 0.00835732771292667, 
0.000605283328636722, 0.00784271102929999, 0.00255437290326066, 
-0.0032625936879903, -0.00397353895194581, -0.355146125402815, 
-0.00793441071373612, 0.00689714297475791, -0.00372780136958125, 
-0.0262747430208002, 0.00581160674981317, 0.0088867911836202, 
0.00817373627163204, 0.00605459264913445, -0.000813552953860299, 
-0.00572686016059428, 0.0085752835454333, 0.00218821368611202, 
-0.01018183248399, 0.00440824333921507, 0.0137465860636734, -0.00341746913593323, 
-0.00509231058802971, 0.0054145349729139, -0.0031023761208035, 
-0.00110482521626189, 0.00501064944461538, 0.00945774961382844, 
-0.00380705634583806, -0.00948635245091245, -0.00146222596289983, 
-0.00370215655722352, -0.00513753457982663, 0.0129818903873515, 
-0.0111827601634213, -0.0176693916234096, 0.00530911119374079, 
0.0160707699763676, -0.00477377186858107, -0.0158312387400629, 
0.00503017722309765, 0.00263288815705768, 0.00538156166178961, 
0.000658087601926903, 0.0170486740468151, -0.00286195741800309, 
0.00153462023795305, -0.00571787204713022, -0.222063008297471, 
-0.00523202526022366, 0.00569066504308259, 0.00268118088286884, 
-0.0301142810794384, 0.0035117619074307, 0.0137738077251694, 
0.0174852453321922, 0.00891838713710508, -0.00867237491187286, 
0.00623632886560044, 0.0164599455751195, 0.00152125863629342, 
0.00208839060419683, 0.0106179758748389, 0.0131781823964128, 
-0.0024532931939566, 0.000900210917833641, 0.00671200821301252, 
-0.00514750921862546, -0.0025135481903864, -0.00474794044628248, 
-0.00234420821571471, -0.000389215774340291, -0.00591920845014461, 
0.00980912496690811, 0.0032704610691041, -0.00465840907768502, 
0.00555370042881158, -0.0258900301781256, -0.0221368882322849, 
0.0029463400572015, 0.0109680614349516, -0.00648775310993824, 
-0.0120998722567077, 0.00625614346363184, 0.00673056210013877, 
0.0156728867267276, -0.0008522536951417, 0.00714808876822038, 
-0.0020660381781391, -0.000967036378234412, -0.0107306692144323
), rollmeanx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.00298044584668048, 
0.00464566284973703, 0.00298925253792591, 0.00313526187710919, 
0.00588391615160814, 0.00584654778711802, 0.00462027271102059, 
0.00241738799545827, 0.00200382560097712, 0.00205154695948561, 
0.00155527159167654, -0.000438834140637924, -0.0013822504669317, 
-0.00117413292110016, -0.00203201524490424, -0.00137362266184867, 
-0.00178952004896222, -0.00154857251389704, 0.000243623928569883, 
-0.000874769693501565, -0.00284520415043736, -0.00248659702860049, 
-0.000735918914292995, -0.0018186088824879, -0.0014270023980849, 
-0.00204095358672166, -0.00136178975758109, -0.000109179864252296, 
-0.00131273109610267, 0.00044748202970538, 0.00282190962088063, 
0.00237385725218809, 0.000980188708409815, -0.0339527827906973, 
-0.0340362807342542, -0.0339730472629555, -0.0347787632177186, 
-0.0382419702910913, -0.0377213379489737, -0.0376169299335417, 
-0.0370549935967045, -0.036123274962992, -0.0358072763631835, 
-0.000865349838961441, 0.0007856195869555, 0.000314726658090912, 
-0.00033067645334996, 0.00273762218265157, 0.00353112011403759, 
0.00230069408208225, 0.000974089396116077, 0.000910083628494023, 
0.000681201311799703, 0.00114340480623294, 0.000786941396151151, 
0.00151389498892279, 0.00215137260273798, 0.000761913023725232, 
-0.000758968178932093, -0.000787436921061122, -0.000791959320240814, 
-3.52237787970495e-05, -0.000843262183058831, -0.0024997188237736, 
-0.00246987264886106, -0.00180857061260715, -0.00190524216488145, 
-0.0025397307937965, -0.00189049047519675, -0.00125698600376863, 
-0.000205076379607008, -0.00143745665814947, 0.00138568676287417, 
0.00286643018341482, 0.00248898108783604, 0.000310116885486266, 
-0.0214188067574027, -0.0203588854094188, -0.0202928366274203, 
-0.0202880073548392, -0.023837591628962, -0.0235522241984116, 
-0.0238797108305762, -0.0218449905555566, -0.0211066138656414, 
-0.0214020641521157, 0.00142786956419144, 0.00359706664772575, 
0.00318012600704683, 0.00312084697917963, 0.00719407267460736, 
0.00816071472350556, 0.00653800463159296, 0.00487950119015711, 
0.00465886329774785, 0.00501134986707259, 0.00413636216147391, 
0.00201557355933371, 0.0016290268741329, 0.00138126623627919, 
-0.000272452196219162, -0.000609357939169628, -3.69825128635584e-05, 
-0.000592844512415424, -0.000708675290835518, -0.00278292738678553, 
-0.00474526139097538, -0.00397583334062698, -0.00264460637556035, 
-0.00325446010912014, -0.00387252648977645, -0.00422782464010407, 
-0.00388181453700061, -0.00184868495655934, -0.00248928036895467, 
0.000814531525679931, 0.00282161653109451, 0.00243027888755092, 
0.000260405822612528), rollsdx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.0134841568195999, 0.0142102103925022, 0.0133617900776779, 
0.0133513079444992, 0.00720300348777936, 0.00720218488402019, 
0.0066933457287114, 0.00634903067804303, 0.00673015322975725, 
0.00672351799074568, 0.00678942802961725, 0.00385761371806388, 
0.00434719025872052, 0.0046179237036809, 0.00557599792443561, 
0.00684948020241074, 0.00676812001759355, 0.00661996487436154, 
0.00781523887100851, 0.00840542133855674, 0.0105901706529699, 
0.0106685462381951, 0.0111710670679376, 0.0110765150259844, 0.0107805043170853, 
0.0100557477605009, 0.0102515759659759, 0.0106288134181471, 0.00966211558692595, 
0.00955510543729772, 0.00578872326420001, 0.00609211488458235, 
0.00574740309766703, 0.112976854387956, 0.112955109139078, 0.112980351066087, 
0.112705243098847, 0.111760609431317, 0.111973609162597, 0.112021291860913, 
0.112259036897868, 0.112608787611361, 0.112713414274796, 0.0108370376131496, 
0.0108978560310096, 0.0107044567314341, 0.0111601414489364, 0.00646492261696063, 
0.00731519373885582, 0.00734898883967546, 0.00736835445412688, 
0.00732195255143012, 0.00741697708347617, 0.00711097945850556, 
0.00677861308008291, 0.00731422581505028, 0.00640260188748834, 
0.00730279244956732, 0.00570760955999991, 0.00572303229458311, 
0.00572682863211845, 0.00699715000072969, 0.00781004948429501, 
0.00945506088599968, 0.00948183569894266, 0.0105738720243143, 
0.010598563559126, 0.0112714010510982, 0.0115245038249566, 0.0115877964390116, 
0.0116735206347549, 0.0107398588037852, 0.011571832681135, 0.00965048221251629, 
0.00961808834911209, 0.00861511313052298, 0.0710011590048217, 
0.0711727459280912, 0.0711992266027793, 0.0712009559938597, 0.0706618069135388, 
0.0707773921050657, 0.0705759483304227, 0.0715359995763646, 0.071841585236276, 
0.0717773132977845, 0.0135599568444965, 0.0141004602638644, 0.0140933169605556, 
0.0140968950343196, 0.00798765419203688, 0.00807692022915802, 
0.00844556579314001, 0.00764769054788447, 0.00754941651863466, 
0.00691330255424837, 0.00728477294878403, 0.00632186623256007, 
0.00647184586794521, 0.00649967123494101, 0.00597070454265456, 
0.00516857370156232, 0.00525784228032607, 0.00543847992799762, 
0.00527550470494566, 0.00955597962169792, 0.0113423807347606, 
0.0116002247919026, 0.0125344993925396, 0.0125609042910873, 0.0128552074244012, 
0.0124786360633152, 0.0127545719186988, 0.0141600338472121, 0.0139309924988578, 
0.0114638806205139, 0.00832687176592357, 0.0084118832879582, 
0.0087564030983619), roll_sharpe = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 6685936.72065089, 8017614.08588343, 7018420.49412074, 
7390175.58759154, 303457831.38321, 301701990.16466, 343915160.124637, 
234319932.365587, 145122636.528603, 149313338.457622, 107805345.140361, 
-513696634.595997, -890314621.582531, -559092284.016373, -376976210.725815, 
-91112795.8598865, -126007475.754857, -121801635.87812, 8356196.78334217, 
-20849530.8685462, -21359871.763186, -17991989.5949062, -4230158.78094462, 
-10907459.3475125, -9800073.06957493, -19850034.8662731, -12026988.4026027, 
-804856.828796049, -15588869.806185, 5618212.74691359, 434139357.655666, 
282887772.972616, 156297275.131569, -1844.70949236578, -1851.02676904941, 
-1845.52487756475, -1912.46516501926, -2193.29199296906, -2142.93355275844, 
-2132.4578924304, -2078.45287781833, -1994.92100566292, -1968.30892082855, 
-5789470.07687758, 5111012.83362099, 2239290.17721102, -1910094.15459264, 
242413530.602272, 168571180.195937, 107329952.244829, 44848329.2430647, 
43246080.3576327, 30348748.7220495, 62885843.8430733, 54984232.2037732, 
72319252.6797467, 199955402.250585, 36682642.0431574, -125300350.018944, 
-128258096.728735, -128567718.189978, -2100051.88283564, -29019751.9921323, 
-33080305.4832977, -32226447.4516634, -13682492.5573323, -14246728.2791774, 
-13960409.9188887, -9299579.50478395, -6016253.88136516, -946033.172647721, 
-10060090.7869726, 6678121.87804663, 34244930.9891507, 30239721.4485301, 
6534622.28640464, -11870.4745751393, -11147.7029903439, -11090.8894943484, 
-11086.9035534244, -13531.2737991098, -13260.476946954, -13637.835605511, 
-11660.8071126149, -11029.073503579, -11233.6184909524, 3114562.13693613, 
6453302.74222076, 5719765.60187294, 5606026.48211451, 221247589.049459, 
237410120.344228, 152160342.169442, 186519350.922088, 189982252.319422, 
317341525.476637, 201622249.257587, 199605333.614001, 143478695.887835, 
119074960.747121, -35905618.217015, -165203371.531602, -9203619.27340462, 
-124610074.081346, -173431195.233419, -34924146.3939243, -25277786.0464064, 
-18927625.9791942, -8547243.41782084, -10408171.0343201, -11030595.382811, 
-13972733.3601454, -11500198.7808806, -3247442.34902245, -4744205.82362176, 
4113861.09463618, 70483686.0815983, 57701874.5526117, 5058502.40572489
)), row.names = c(NA, -129L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`6` = 6L, `50` = 50L, `94` = 94L), class = "omit"))
```

And this is the dput of price_data:

```
structure(list(symbol = c("XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", "XLY", 
"XLY", "XLY", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", "XLV", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", 
"XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI", "XLI"), date = structure(c(1566172800, 
1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566864000, 1566950400, 
1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 1567728000, 
1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568592000, 
1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 1569283200, 
1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 
1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 1570665600, 
1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 1571356800, 
1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566864000, 
1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 
1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 
1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 
1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 
1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 
1570665600, 1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 
1571356800, 1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 
1566864000, 1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567468800, 1567555200, 
1567641600, 1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400,
```

The problem occours in pct_change calculation, becouse the script make the pct_change calculations between two different etfs time series and this wrongly inflates (deflates) the sharpe values of the etf with highest (lowest) price.
Thanks for every contribution

Comment: we need the dput of price_data, not price_data_02. But you should first do a `group_by` on symbol before the mutates. Then the calculations you are doing will be done on each ticker instead of on everything.

Comment: Hi, tnx for Your answer.  When I try to use group_by(symbol) I get    [Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using group_by solved the problem. Tnx Phiver

```
library(quantmod)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(roll)

###
tickers = c('xly', 'xlv', 'xli'); forex = c('EURUSD')   
tiingo_api_key("XXXX") #wts = c(0.1,0.2,0.25,0.25,0.2) 
price_data <- tq_get(tickers, from = '2019-08-19', to = '2019-10-19',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- tq_get(forex, from = '2019-08-19', to = '2019-10-19',
                     get = "tiingo")
forex_data <- forex_data[ ,c(2, 8)]

price_data <- price_data %>%
  # join datasets using date column.
  # non key columns from rhs that have the same names as columns in 
  # the lhs get assigned the suffix "_forex_data"
  left_join(forex_data, by = c("date"), suffix = c("", "_forex_data")) %>%
  # calculate new value of adjusted by dividing by forex value
  mutate(adjusted = adjusted / adjusted_forex_data) %>%
  # exclude adjusted_forex_data column from result
  select(-adjusted_forex_data)

price_data <- na.omit(price_data) 
price_data <- price_data[ ,c(1, 2,8)]

colnames(price_data)[3] <- "adjClose"

by_etf <- price_data %>% group_by(symbol)

price_data_02 <- by_etf %>%
  mutate(lagx = lag(adjClose)) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (adjClose - lagx)/adjClose)%>%
  mutate(rollmeanx = roll_mean(pct_change, width = 10),rollsdx = roll_sd(pct_change, width=10)) %>%
  mutate(roll_sharpe = rollmeanx / rollsdx^5)
```